# Unit Test SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, unit-testing

How do you unit test the following procedure:

```
procedure some_prc as
begin
    select t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, count(*) from t inner join t1 on t.f1 = t1.f2
    group t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d;
end;
```

the query is run by sqlplus.

Comment: Is unit testing even feasible for SQL SPs? The unit test would highly depend on the data in the table, so it'd fail if I added/removed records...

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by unit testing though - as it stands now it looks fine and provided your data is correct then it will work.  If you know your data then it should be easy to work out some test cases manually on the DB and then compare against the results from your query.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar I don't understand in principal what is the method of DB unit testing? The only method I can think of is grabbing data, pasting it into a spreadhseet, doing counts there and then run the query and past results into another spredo and finally compare them using formulas. Looks too cumbersome and non-practical altogether.

Comment: That's what I mean - what's the point of unit testing stored procedures?

Comment: The point is simple - all changes have to be covered up by Unit Tests. I'm in charge of doing that.

Comment: still won't work, in pl/sql you'll need to select INTO something.  What are you trying to test exactly?

Comment: @tbone - in Oracle you've to use a cursor, in MSSQL just select will suffice. I've changed the logic for a simple query which looks the same as the one I posted. I need to prove that it 'works correctly' on its own.

Comment: Testing this procedure is meaningless - even if you added a INTO clause (which is required for this to be correct PL/SQL), this procedure has no observable side effects. So what do you want to verify? Show us a *real* example, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform an automated, repeatable unit test would require an environment where you have total control of the data - e.g. a local install of the database on your own PC, or a dedicated database or schema on the server that only you can access.

Only then can you do what you would need to do i.e.

1. Run a pre-test script to set up the initial condition for the test, i.e. the exact data it will work on.
2. Run your procedure.
3. Run a script to inspect the data after running the procedure and check that it matches your expectations.

Even in a controlled environment you are going to have complications if your data involves dates, since the value of SYSDATE is probably not under your control!

There is a mechanism for Unit Tests along these lines built into SQL Developer.  Also there is a tool call [utPLSQL](http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/) you could investigate.  I can't recommend for or against either as I haven't really used them.

Comment: With respect to sysdate, try this for a system-wide change to the value: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams084.htm Wouldn't try it on production ;)